# how to feed value from database using ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".submit").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var user_name = $("input#name").val();
        var password = $("input#pwd").val();
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>" + "index.php/ajax_post_controller/user_data_submit",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                name: user_name,
                pwd: password
            },
            success: function(res) {
                if (res) {
                    // Show Entered Value
                    jQuery("div#result").show();
                    jQuery("div#value").html(res.name);
                    jQuery("div#value_pwd").html(res.pwd);
                }
            }
        });
    });
});

// the function of controller that the url: contains
public function user_data_submit() {
    $data = array(
        'username' => $this - > input - > post('name'),
        'pwd' => $this - > input - > post('pwd')
    );
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

the code is used to take value from the input field and feed it on the html based on id. but my problem is i need to feed it from select query which bring value from the database that already has the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[https://openenergymonitor.org/emon/node/107](https://webdevdoor.com/javascript-ajax/dynamic-select-list-jquery-php)

```
 $(function () 
 {
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------
// 2) Send a http request with AJAX http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------
$.ajax({                                      
  url: 'api.php',                  //the script to call to get data          
  data: "",                        //you can insert url argumnets here to pass to api.php
                                   //for example "id=5&parent=6"
  dataType: 'json',                //data format      
  success: function(data)          //on recieve of reply
  {
    var id = data[0];              //get id
    var vname = data[1];           //get name
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------
    // 3) Update html content
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------
    $('#output').html("<b>id: </b>"+id+"<b> name: </b>"+vname); //Set output element html
    //recommend reading up on jquery selectors they are awesome 
    // http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/
  } 
});
 }); 
 </script>
```

THis is not the edxact answer based on my question but it exactly resembles the answer that i want which is the getting id and name from the database